# sql files not being run when installing extensions

Tags: magento-1.9, database, extensions, sql, installation

The last couple of manual (not through Magento Connect) extensions I've had to install have all had issues with the database tables not being created. These are the extensions which the installation consists of uploading two folders.

The database setup file should be triggered after a page reload so that database tables are created however they aren't. In the backend the extension shows up under **System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced** – however, they doesn't show up under `core_resources` in the database.

Is there a setting somewhere that I've somehow flicked off? Or a way I can repair or track down what is causing these sql setup files from not being triggered?

Comment: have you clear all cache?

Comment: Yes, before and after installing the extensions.